# Is there a list of possible relative date formats I can pass to Carbon::parse() in PHP?

Tags: php, php-carbon

Carbon::parse() accepts relative date strings, like 'first day of next month'. My team members want to add an input field for this in a VueJS / Laravel application, but I'm concerned about validation.

As it turns out, all of these strings are parsed by Carbon without throwing an error:

- 'first day of next month'
- 'first day of next week'
- 'first day of next year'

However the latter two give incorrect results, provided that the date at time of writing is 2023-10-26:

- 'first day of next month': 2023-11-01 (correct)
- 'first day of next week': 2023-09-01 (incorrect)
- 'first day of next year': 2023-10-01 (incorrect)

How do I know in advance what formats are supported and actually work without giving incorrect results?

I searched the documentation which states:

> The string passed to Carbon::parse or to new Carbon can represent a relative time (next sunday, tomorrow, first day of next month, last year) or an absolute time (first day of December 2008, 2017-01-06). You can test if a string will produce a relative or absolute date with Carbon::hasRelativeKeywords().

Are these literally the only possibilities or is there more?

I asked ChatGPT and it knew that 'first day of next year' would not work, but it could not provide me with the source of information. It said something about 'general knowledge'...

Comment: I'd assume (especially since Carbon inherits from DateTime), it's talking about https://www.php.net/manual/en/datetime.formats.php#datetime.formats.relative

Comment: https://carbon.nesbot.com/docs/#api-testing also mentions : "The list of words that are considered to be relative modifiers are:..." followed by some info about what words are involved

Comment: Thank you. The first link (to the PHP manual) helps me somewhat in the right direction. It mentions that "first day of ... is usually best used together with a month name following it...". So apparently it works for months only. Just the phrase "is usually" sounds that the writers aren't sure either.

Answer (score -2):

When using `Carbon::parse()`, you can provide various date formats to parse a date string.

Here are some examples of the relative date formats that you can pass to `Carbon::parse()`:

1. `tomorrow`
2. `next Thursday`
3. `last Monday`
4. `first day of next month`
5. `3 days ago`
6. `+2 weeks`
7. `next week Tuesday`
8. `now`

You can use terms like `tomorrow`, `next`, `last`, and `ago` to specify relative dates, and you can combine them with days, weeks, months, or other time units.

Example:

```
$date = Carbon::parse('next Wednesday');
echo $date->toDateString(); // Outputs the date of the next Wednesday

Carbon::now()->startOfWeek()->addWeek(); // Output first day of next week
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I could not find why something like "first day of next week" would not work correctly, and it would not give any error either. It looks like example 4, but apparently this only works for months, and not weeks or years. It would be helpful to have a reference in the documentation where this is mentioned.

Comment: You can simple do by `Carbon::now()->startOfWeek()->addWeek();` which is the solution of your problem.

Comment: Yes, that is true for this specific case. My problem is that apparently there is no reliable way to validate a relative date string that was given by a user. The user may enter something that passes the validation done by Carbon and still get incorrect results. So passing user input to Carbon::parse() may be a bad idea.

Comment: I am as well seaerching for a set of regular expressions applicable to validate user input passed to carbon::parse.